# declare a string type variable as a global variable in one aspx file,which is better to Initialize with null or string.empty

Tags: c#

which is best for a string type global variable in one aspx page?

Answer (score 1):

I personally use String.Empty, but the choice was a flip of a coin for me.

I find that using `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` to test my strings means that it doesn't matter how they were initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no need to initialize a field to `null` - it will be that automatically. And there isn't a *huge* benefit in `string.Empty` over just `""`, which I find more readable (since the compiler automatically uses interned strings for any literals in the source code).

So personally, I would either use:

```
string foo = "";
```

or just:

```
string foo; // defaults to null
```

I make a habit of using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for most tests, which removes much of the difference between the two.

Comment: thank you for your answer,yes,I use string.IsNullorEmpty for validation too.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on how the variable will be used. If you won't need to check for empty strings then initialize it to string.Empty to avoid performing null checks.

As an aside, placing a global variable in an ASPX page might not be the best choice for storing your data. A separate class with the specific purpose of managing the string might be a better place. Also, it would be safer to make the variable private and provide public properties or methods for accessing it - that way you can always ensure the value is valid.

Comment: can you give some samples that how to use a separate class to  store data? in my case, the global variables in page only use in the current page,not others.